# How to implement a shrink animation for a control in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I want a control (e.g. a GroupBox) to show a grow animation when it becomes visible and a shrink animation, when the visibility is changed to "Collapsed".

Therefore, I created a style which implements an animated grow and shrink effect as shown here in a small sample application (shown below).

However, only the **grow** animation is shown. Instead of showing the **shrink** animation, the groupbox disappears at once.

Can anyone tell me, why?
And even better, how to fix it?

```
<Window x:Class="ShrinkTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="ExpandableElement">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5 0" />
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" AccelerationRatio="0.2" DecelerationRatio="0.4"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" AccelerationRatio="0.2" DecelerationRatio="0.4"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Margin="8" Width="140" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Expand / Shrink</Button>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="--- Header ---"/>

        <GroupBox x:Name="GroupBox" Grid.Row="2" Header="GroupBox" Style="{StaticResource ExpandableElement}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="Test Test Test"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test Test Test"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test Test Test"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test Test Test"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test Test Test"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="--- Footer ---"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Would it be `Collapsed` instead of `Hidden` with either Visibility already set as a default on the object already? Or have you tried ditching the second Trigger for `Hidden` and just enter the second animation to the one trigger for `Visible` except as `ExitActions` instead of `EnterActions`? Would be my first thoughts without testing.

Comment: The Hidden trigger is executed after the Visibility is changed to Hidden so either your storyboard is played when the control is Hidden or WPF is smart enough to know that it isn't shown and doesn't play the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheridan is right. As soon as a control becomes invisible, it doesn't matter, which animation you apply to it. :-)

So I created a special ExpandingContentControl:

```
public class ExpandingContentControl : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(ExpandingContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value); }
    }

    public ExpandingContentControl()
    {
        Visibility = IsExpanded ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

But there was also a problem with the style: Creating two triggers which are bound to different values of the same property obviously doesn't work.
Instead, I'm now using just one trigger where the EnterAction implements growing and the ExitAction implements shrinking the control:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ExpandingContentControl" >
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5 1" />
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" KeyTime="00:00:00"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="0" To="1" 
                                         Duration="0:0:0.3" DecelerationRatio="0.4"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" KeyTime="00:00:0.2"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Just think about it for a minute... your problem is that you can see your animation when it's visible, but you can't when it is hidden. *That* is also your answer to why... because it is hidden. I know, that's fairly unsatisfactory answer, but that's just how it is.

As to how to fix it... well saying it is simple, but implementing it is not. Simply put, you have to run your animation until it ends and *then* set the `Visibility` to `Hidden`. So unfortunately this means that nice, simple setting the `Visibility` property in the `Trigger` is no longer viable... it's ok to make it visible, just not for hiding.

In my case, I have a whole framework that I built my animations into. Basically speaking though, when I remove items from the collections, internally the item is not actually removed, but instead its exit animation is started. Only when that animation is complete will the internal collection *actually* remove the item.

So if you can be bothered, then you'll have to implement something like this where, rather than setting the `Visibility` property to `Hidden`, you set another property to `true` which triggers the animation and when the `Completed` event from that animation is called, *then* you set the `Visibility` property to `Hidden`.